# convert to epoch and back

Tags: perl, date, time

I've used the following two perl command lines successfully:

```
perl -e 'use Time::Local; print timelocal(7,51,10,22,3,2014), "\n";'
```

which returns `1398163867`, and

```
perl -e 'print scalar(localtime(1398163867)), "\n"'
```

which returns `Tue Apr 22 10:51:07 2014`

What I would like to do is replace `7,51,10,22,3,2014`, and `1398163867` with a variable containing those values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a shell variable:

```
t=7,51,10,22,3,2014
perl -MTime::Local -le 'print timelocal split ",", shift' -- "$t"

t=1398163867
perl -le 'print scalar localtime shift' -- "$t"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!